# Neo4j Cypher query performance issue

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have simple (at least in terms of understanding) cypher query that tooks 10-15 seconds on average random start node:

```
START hospital1 = Node:Hospitals(id="xxx")  
MATCH (hospital1)-[:CHILD_PROVIDER]->(provider1)-[referral:REFERRED]-(provider2)<-[:CHILD_PROVIDER]-(hospital2)  
WHERE hospital1 <> hospital2  
RETURN hospital1, SUM(referral.count), hospital2;
```

Part of PROFILE output (skipped all node references):

```
==> ColumnFilter(symKeys=["hospital1", "hospital2", "  INTERNAL_AGGREGATEd314d0d2- c365-4373-8bc8-047a3824abc4"], returnItemNames=["hospital1", "SUM(referral.count)", "hospital2"], _rows=29, _db_hits=0)
==> EagerAggregation(keys=["hospital1", "hospital2"], aggregates=["(  INTERNAL_AGGREGATEd314d0d2-c365-4373-8bc8-047a3824abc4,Sum(Product(referral,count(37),true)))"], _rows=29, _db_hits=1008)
==>   Filter(pred="NOT(hospital1 == hospital2)", _rows=1008, _db_hits=0)
==>     TraversalMatcher(trail="(hospital1)-[  UNNAMED77:CHILD_PROVIDER WHERE true AND true]->(provider1)-[referral:REFERRED WHERE true AND true]-(provider2)<-[  UNNAMED140:CHILD_PROVIDER WHERE true AND true]-(hospital2)", _rows=10192, _db_hits=54096)
```

(hospital) -- (provider) is something like 1:100-250

(provider) -- (provider) differs from 0 to 1:150 or so

_db_hits=54096 looks very high for me and I think it's the reason for slow response.

I have 2 major question:

1) should I consider adding pre-calculated relations or I can improve performance somehow with current graph?

2) in general, how many traversal actions are ok per query? It looks very good at 1:10:10:1, but what size is good sign that some changes are required to graph (considering that I need to collect information from all matched relationships, rather than find shortest path etc)

Comment: How fast is your query when executed multiple times? If that is fast enough consider tuning caches ( http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/configuration-caches.html). How large is your graph? #nodes and #rels ?

Comment: Cached result is fast, but considering the size it'll be too high probability of missed cache.  There are ~5M nodes, ~65M relationships, ~85M properties, ~35Gb size.

Comment: What Neo4j version are you using? Could you try it with 2.0-RC1 ? There were some improvements in the matching. Also your current setup creates all paths first and then filters them down that should be automatically pulled into the matcher.

Comment: Regarding caches. Usually as you don't access too many properties, only nodes, relationships and some of the rel-properties (count) will be pulled into the cache.